# What's the purpose of a password in symmetric cryptography?

Tags: python, security, cryptography, passwords, symmetric-key

I found the Python package to encrypt some data and see [this](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#using-passwords-with-fernet) in python Cryptography:

> It is possible to use passwords with Fernet(symmetric key). To do this, you need to run the password through a key derivation function such as PBKDF2HMAC, bcrypt or scrypt.

But, it turns out that a password works in the same way as a key(use password/key to en/decrypt). So why bother to use password instead of key itself?

I mean why not just use key itself:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = Fernet.generate_key()
token = Fernet(key).encrypt(b"my deep dark secret")
Fernet(key).decrypt(token)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A password is something that can be remembered by a person whereas a key is usually not remembered, because it is long (at least 128 bit or Hex-encoded in 32 characters) and is supposed to be really random (indistinguishable from random noise). If you want to encrypt something with a key, but this key cannot be transmitted by asymmetric cryptography and instead should be given over the phone or should never be written anywhere, then you can't simply generate a random key and use that. You need have a password/passphrase in place to derive the key from.

Example 1:

A personal password safe like KeePass needs a key for encryption/decryption. A user will not be able to simply remember that key, therefore we have a much shorter password, which can be remembered. Now, the security lies in the fact that a *slow* key derivation function is used to derive a key from the password, so an attacker still has trouble brute-forcing the key even though it depends on a much shorter password.

Example 2:

You compress a document and use the encryption of the compression software. Now you can send the container via e-mail, but you can't send the password along with it. So, you call the person you've sent the e-mail to and tell them the password. A password is much easier to transmit than a long and random key in this way.